# Is Organization Name on an Azure AD have to be unique?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Our organization has an O365 subscription with an associated AD.  We now want to set up a B2C AD and, from everything I've read, that requires that we create a new tenant.

I found [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started) for creating a B2C directory.

In creating a new B2C tenant, the first things you're asked for is an Organization Name and the initial domain name.

In this case, the owning organization of the B2C tenant is the same organization.  The B2C tenant is simply used by the same org to host/authenticate external customers, etc.  So, can we use the same Organization Name and simply use a different domain name for the tenant or will that cause issues?

Is it the Organization name or the domain name (or both) that is used to name the tenant itself and keep it unique?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer: Yes, you can have two tenants with the same Organization Name. (Verified) Domains are the ones that need to be unique across all of Azure AD.** While the tenant ID is the primary key of the tenant, the initial domain acts as a alternate key that also needs to be unique.

It is worth understanding that the organization name and initial domain name have different effects/implications in Azure AD B2C when compared to regular Azure AD.

The organization name does not have to be unique across organizations as it's purely a display value. You can give your B2C tenant the same Organization name as your corporate tenant. When picking the the organization name, keep in mind that it is shown to your consumers/customers in the verification email.

Domain names (including the initial domain) do have to be unique across all Azure AD tenants (regular and B2C) so you can't have the same domain in your corporate tenant and Azure AD B2C tenant. This shouldn't really impact your application because, unlike users of regular Azure AD which sign-in with a upn@domain.com user, in B2C users signin with a local or social account which can have any username/email.

The only place where the domain is visible is in the login URL which has to contain any of the following:

- TenantID (https://login.microsoftonline.com/96de2ca6-60d7-4e85-bcbc-ac368dbb9528)
- Initial Domain (https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com)
- A Verified Domain (https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourverifieddomain.com)

For this case, you can register a verified subdomain such as login.yourcompany.com in the B2C tenant.

**Note:** There's also a feature ask for Azure AD B2C to support completely custom login URLs, you can vote and follow that ask in the Azure AD B2C UserVoice forum: [Customer-owned domains](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!